# How to keep a null date value from reverting back the default date after page refresh? (Oracle APEX)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm pretty new to APEX and programming as a whole, so bear with me. I have a table I created using dynamic PL/SQL and have a TO and FROM datepicker to set the range of rows to select. It is functioning great so far but I'm having a problem with the defaults for both datepickers. I've set the FROM datepicker to default to one year in the past and the TO datepicker is set to the current date. I've set them both using a SQL expression in the default field. Whenever you change the date and refresh, the table selects the correct rows. BUT if you want to remove the dates in both pickers so that you can see every row in the table, the null values are being reset to the default values after refreshing the page. I feel like there's probably a very simple way to fix this, but I'm at a loss. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

An item gets its value from **session state**; if it doesn't exist, then from **source**; if it doesn't exist (and the item is still `NULL`), then **default value** is used.

Therefore, what you did is just the opposite of what you want - if everything else is `NULL`, default value is used.

What to do? Don't set default value for the item - use it directly in report's `WHERE` clause. Something like this:

```
select whatever
from your_table
where some_conditions
  and date_column between nvl(:P1_DATE_FROM, add_months(trunc(sysdate), -12))
                      and nvl(:P1_DATE_TO  , trunc(sysdate))
```

So:

- if `P1_DATE_FROM` and/or `P1_DATE_TO` are set, these values will be used
- if they are `NULL`, they will be set to *previous year* and *today*

Of course, you'd remove both item's default values.

Comment: I'll give this a try right now! Thank you.

Comment: Is there a way to have a default value visible inside of the datepicker upon page load, but have the ability to remove the default date and set it to null? That's the outcome I'm looking for. To see the year long date range when first navigating to the report, but having the ability to clear both dates and refresh to see all rows in the table.

Comment: @AJBeav Try to create a process in a new session point. In this process you define the "default" value for these items. This process will run only one time when user enter the application. After he do something with this item the value will be what he does with it. Of course, dont use default value field in the item.